# Checkbox that unchecks other checkboxes – Maya MEL

Tags: checkbox, maya, mel

I just recently started learning MEL scripting and I barely scrape the basics. But for now, I am able to write my own script which enables showing/hiding of objects in Maya 2015. The problem I am facing now is that I want a master checkbox that checks/unchecks other checkbox. The method I have now only enables me to change one children checkbox but not the rest.

ETC - `None` checkbox is `on`. All other children checkboxes are `off`. `None` checkbox is `off`. All other children are `on`. Right now I can manage to get one children checkbox to be toggle `on` and `off` with the master `None` checkbox.

Here's my code:

```
checkBox -label "None" -align "center" -v false -onCommand "OnNoneProcedure" -offCommand "offNoneProcedure" -changeCommand "checkBox -edit -value (!#1) checkboxNurbsCurves";
checkBox -label "NurbsCurves" -align "center" -v true -onCommand "OnNurbsCurvesProcedure" -offCommand "offNurbsCurvesProcedure" checkboxNurbsCurves;
```

Am I doing the right way with the `changecommand` method? if yes, how do I get the other children checkbox to `on` and `off`? or do I query the master `None` checkbox -v then use the -v of `None` to toggle the -v of children checkbox?

Answer (score 1):

probably the easiest thing to do would be to create a procedure that sets all the checkboxes you want to the desired state, then specify that procedure as the changeCommand.

In order to get that to work, you'll probably want to name the checkboxes and/or store them into some string array variable that you can loop through to set within your procedure...  Fortunately, that's really easy since the checkbox command returns the full name of the checkbox it creates.

Comment: thanks silent_sight ;D

make sense to do that. But one of my friend recommend me not to use -on/off command with changecommand. Its either one or the other. Moreever, he teach me to do it in another way by using "toggleon" to edit the value of the "children" checkboxes. 
So yea haha thanks for the tip!

Comment: yeah, the maya docs for the checkbox command even say to only use `changeCommand` or `onCommand`/`offCommand` and not both.  Generally, I don't work in commands for checkboxes when I create ui's - I tend to just use them as toggles for various options and query them when the "execution button" is clicked - ie: set a few T/F settings and then use those when running the actual code instead of having each checkbox run some code.  Sorry I didn't notice that before...

Comment: I don't see `toggleon` in the checkbox command docs... maybe it's hidden or obsolete?  I was thinking the `value` flag is what you would use to set the checked/unchecked state in your proc, but if all of your checkboxes run some command when they're toggled, they may all get triggered; however, you could probably get away with it if the only thing it does is to toggle any 'children' checkboxes on/off

Comment: yea i cant find toggle in the checkbox docs as well. There are plenty of "hidden" commands that doesnt comes with the help doc lol.

Let me share with u the code that does the trick.

Comment: proc int OnNoneToggle(int $t)
  {
  checkBox -edit -value (!$t) checkboxNurbsCurves;
  checkBox -edit -value (!$t) checkboxNurbsSurfaces;
  checkBox -edit -value (!$t) checkboxNurbsCVs;
    // declare a procedure to find the current panel with focus and hide everything 
proc OnNoneProcedure()
  {
   // find current panel with focus 
   $result = ` getPanel -wf `;
   
   // hide all objects in current panel
   {
    modelEditor -e -allObjects 0 $result;
   }
   OnNoneToggle(1);
   
   // print the result
   {
    print("all objects hidden!\n");
   } 
   
  }
  ;

Comment: i am actually just toggling a (number (1)) so when that button is on, the (number(1)) will be toggle from its initial state to another state which will be (0) now. then i take this new number to put into the V of the children checkbox.

Comment: if u dont mind me asking, what would you do if you have 32 checkboxes in total and you need to calculate each combination(order does not matters) to activate each different procedure? to manually calculate each combination would kill me honestly haha

Comment: that is a really difficult question to answer.... 32 t/f combinations is 4,294,967,296 possible combinations (provided my math is correct on that, heh)....  Without a better idea of what you're trying to do with this ui, I'm really not sure - it's possible some of those combinations could be collapsed/combined or something...

Comment: yea sadly, im trying something bigger than my head lol. One of my friends recommend me to use "for loop" to iterate each checkbox with one method. while i understand the general usage of "for loop", i cant get my head to use on my script now lol

Comment: What is your ui for... or... how will it be used?  It's possible you don't even need to manage all the possible combinations... just depends on what you are doing...

Comment: okay i got it working! haha my friend mentored me through the last step. basically this is how it works;
1) query current panel state
2)get results and pass into a array
3)use the results from returned array into another procedure into a new array
4)each result if 0 = off that element, if 1 = on that element
return this new result
5)create shelf button with new result (result = command).

Comment: I would let you take a look at the script if you want XD

Comment: Glad you got it working - I suspected you could query the state of each checkbox and perform an operation for each within your proc instead of a separate proc for every possible checkbox combination...

Answer (score 0):

okay i got it working! haha my friend mentored me through the last step. basically this is how it works; 1) query current panel state 2)get results and pass into a array 3)use the results from returned array into another procedure into a new array 4)each result if 0 = off that element, if 1 = on that element return this new result 5)create shelf button with new result (result = command).